# Error 1064 - you have an eror in your SQL syntax at line... despite the online syntax checkers saying teh code is correct

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sql-insert

I keep getting error 1064 on this INSERT statement, even though I have checked it on a couple of online syntax checkers and they say it is 100% OK. I am running Mysql 8.0.19 on a Mac via MySQL Workbench (I get the same result through PHPMyAdmin).

`` INSERT INTO `tmpRC` (`OrigDateRefd`,`DbkNo`,`RefDocName`,`SpecCustLoc`,`P_Age`,`P_Gender`,`OriginalDiagnosis`,`ClinNotSumry`)
VALUES
(NULL,'62-0016','HINGSTON NG','RPH','10','FEMALE','TB',' '),
(NULL,'62-0017','CONNOR','RPH','18','FEMALE','SECONDARY CA ',' '); ``

The error message is:

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`OriginalDiagnosis`,' at line 1".
```

Strangely enough - I have copied this insert statement from a query I successfully ran a few days ago!  I cannot see what the issue is - any ideas?

Comment: you didn't copy it right. Look closely at [INSERT syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)

Comment: Thank you for a prompt response. I should perhaps have indicated that I have checked the manual for v.8 as suggested and I have searched Stackoverflow for similar questions previously asked.  I have also re-run the query from the other day and it runs without throwing the 1064 error.  My statement appears to me to conform to the syntax specified in the manual: INSERT INTO tablename[`tmpRC`] (column_names [`OrigDateRefd` etc.]) VALUES (NULL, etc.); as I said - I can't see what the issue is - if it is obvious can you provide me with a more specific hint?

Comment: It was me misreading this. Is the ``` correct? Try removing them in case its a different character that looks the same.

Comment: Do you have any triggers running presently?

Comment: @Carlosz Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue  see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5BH7ezuipDrHJ5GkvMHqFw/0

Comment: Please don't forget to respect patient confidentiality.

Comment: @O.Jones "Please don't forget to respect patient confidentiality" - I don't understand the relevance of this comment. Rest assured that none of this data is real and there is no way anyone can link this INSERT statement to an accessible database, nor is there anyway one could identify a patient even if they could access the database: you can't retrieve data from a field that isn't there.

Comment: Great. You are respecting patient confidentiality. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input. There are no triggers on the table.
For future reference in case anyone has a similar problem,  I think the clue is that the online syntax checkers say the syntax in the INSERT statement is correct and P.Salmon has tested it in SQL_Fiddle and it works.  Another clue is that MySQL Workbench kept telling me there was a comma after the  VALUES keyword when it was clear there wasn't one - my conclusion: the file (which I had edited in BBEdit) was somehow corrupted or there were hidden characters in it somehow.  I manually re-typed the query (ie., not copy-and-paste) into a new sql file in BBEdit and it ran perfectly in PHPMyAdmin.  The back-ticks around the column names appear to have no influence on it working in this context, as it runs whether you have them or not. Thank you again for your interest and assistance.